# RPC Control widget - What is proper response for getValue method. How to change setValue to react onRelease instead on onClick of mouse?

Tags: thingsboard

I am having an issues with thingsboard professional edition.
I am using HTML Server Side RPC API.

Basically what I am trying to do is load dashboard and update knob temperature value. The next step is to set temperature value using knob and send it to device.

Issue with getValue method
First of all I open dashboard and I am sending GET request

```
curl -v -X GET https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/v1/*Device Access/Token*/rpc
```

Response is:

```
{"id":241,"method":"getValue","params":null}*
```

So I respond:

```
curl -v -X POST -d "{"result":44}" https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/v1/*Device Access Token*/rpc/241 --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

In place of "{"result":44}" I tried (I think) all possibilities like:

```
"{"method":"getValue","params":44}"
"{"method":"setValue","params":44}"
"{"method":NULL,"params":44}"
"{NULL,44}"
"44"
"{44}" and so on...
```

Can somebody help me how should proper response look like to update knob value when dashboard loads?

2) setValue issue

When I am trying to change temperature value I noticed that there is something weird happening.
Let's say that I want to change value from 50 to 80deg using knob.

If i just "click" and temperature is set somewhere about 80deg when I send GET message response is what i expect:

```
{"id":273,"method":"setValue","params":"81.37"}*
```

But when I click on knob and slide the value from 50deg to 80deg and release the button I don't have proper response. Most of the time I have response like that:

```
{"id":275,"method":"setValue","params":"50.00"}* Closing connection 0
```

Or very close to 50 deg and it doesn't change anymore. How can i fix that issue?

Comment: Did you make progress on this? Your answer may fit my use case as well

Comment: Hey TDawg,
Yes I have fixed that issue. If you want to do it manually you need to increase timeout.
I recommend you to start with this simulator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DOyA3i5NGc

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is more than 2 years old, I think it might help someone never the less:

Regarding GetValue I did many experiments and found that the POST message does not need

```
--header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

and the return value does not need to be in JSON format, but just plain text. So if you use

```
--header "Content-Type:application/text"
```

and as a return value just send e.g.

```
40.0
```

it will be accepted by the knob control.

full command might be something like

```
curls -v -X POST -d 40.0 https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/v1/*Device Access Token*/rpc/241 --header "Content-Type:application/text"
```